# Why won't my created element (input) trigger a event when I set it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');

const siteDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

/* Popup */

const myStuff = prompt('Enter \'columns, rows\' NOTE: 5,20 is recommended on computer, refer to documentation.');

if (myStuff !== '' || myStuff.includes(',') === true) {
  const myStuffArr = myStuff.split(',');
  
  console.log(myStuffArr);
  
  window.amountOfColumns = myStuffArr[0];
  
  window.amountOfRows = myStuffArr[1];

} else {
  window.amountOfColumns = 5;
  
  window.amountOfRows = 20;
}

/* Functions */

function changeItem() {
  alert()
}

var counter = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < window.amountOfRows; x++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < window.amountOfColumns; i++) {
    const myNewElement = document.createElement('input');
    myNewElement.width = siteDocument
    myNewElement.style.fontSize = '2vh';
    counter++
    myNewElement.setAttribute('id', 'myNewElement' + counter)
    console.log(myNewElement.id);
    myNewElement.addEventListener("onfocus", changeItem); 
    sheets.appendChild(myNewElement)
    document.getElementById("sheets").style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + window.amountOfColumns +", 1fr)";
  }
}
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
   inputs[z].style.height = "calc((50vh/" +window.amountOfRows +") - 3px)";
   //inputs[z].style.maxHeight = "calc((80vh/20) - 100px)";
}

/* Fix Issues OR Bugs */
const submitFormula = document.getElementById('submitFormula');

submitFormula.style.fontSize = '1vw';

submitFormula.style.width = '8em';
submitFormula.style.height = '1.5em';

/* Stuff Extra */
/* 

/*  /* Download Excel File

var A = [['n','sqrt(n)']];

for(var j=1; j<10; ++j){ 
    A.push([j, Math.sqrt(j)]);
}

var csvRows = [];

for(var i=0, l=A.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(A[i].join(','));
}

var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

*/
```

```css
#titletext {
  font-size: 5vh;
}

#sheets {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttons > button {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 4vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
}
#itemVisible {
  width: 2vw;
}
#enterFormula {
  width: 8vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup"></div>
    <h1 id="titletext">Excel Sheets</h1>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="" onclick="">File</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Insert</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Page Layout</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Formulas</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Review</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">View</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Developer</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Help</button>
    </div> <br>
    <div id="toolresult"></div>
    <div id="item">
      <input id="itemVisible" disabled></input>
      <input id="enterFormula"></input>
      <input type="submit" id="submitFormula"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="sheets" onchange="getItem()"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So if you look in script.js (the javascript code) you should see that I added an onfocus event to my New Element (s) so basically it's not working and the function is not running :(

Maybe because I created the element, please help? Thanks everyone.

Also, the code is at the for loop and I use setAttribute to set an ID and then I set the onfocus to the function for now, no parameter just for testing.

Comment: Try with `.addEventListener("focus", ...`. The event name is `focus`. `onfocus` is an element attribute to assign a function inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your listener up with an invalid event name, remove `"on"`, so instead of `"onfocus"`, it should just be `.addEventListener("focus", changeItem);`.

The `on` naming convention is used with inline HTML event attributes and also when setting event properties of JavaScript objects, but the actual event names don't include `"on"` and [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expects just the [event name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

If you want to pass arguments to the handler, you'd wrap the function you really want called in an anonymous function that will receive a reference to the event like the following:

```
someElement.addEventListener("focus", function(event){
  someOtherFunction(event, param1, param2, etc....);
});
```

Comment: Wait so how would I add parameters to the eventlistener? say changeItem('test')

Comment: @StudentUser1625 You'd wrap the function reference in an anonymous function. I'll update the answer to show this.